# Contrapositive rule: derivation by contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

I was studying the contrapositive rule of inference these days, and I was able to prove it by manipulating the conditional $p\rightarrow q$ as $\neg p\lor q$.

When searching for similar proofs, I found the following on Wikipedia:

"Let $(A\rightarrow B)\land\neg B$.

For if $A$ were true, then $B$ would have to also be true (by Modus Ponens). However, it is given that $B$ is not true, so we have a contradiction. Therefore, $A$ is not true (assuming that we are dealing with bivalent statements that are either true or false):

$$\color{orange}{(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(\neg B\rightarrow\neg A)}$$"

I tried to redo the proof by myself and got the following:

"Let $(A\rightarrow B)\land\neg B$.

For if $A$ were true, then $B$ would have to also be true (by Modus Ponens). However, it is given that $B$ is not true. Therefore, $A$ can't be true, otherwise a contradiction would arise. (assuming that we are dealing with bivalent statements that are either true or false):

$$\color{blue}{((A\rightarrow B)\land\neg B)\rightarrow\neg A}$$"

**My question is:** did I make a mistake somewhere? Do I have to manipulate the expression that I got to obtain the contrapositive of $A\rightarrow B$?

Comment: Basically you asking why $(M\land N)\to K \iff M\to(N\to K)$.  Is that right?

Comment: Slightly more basic than Bram28's answer using implication $$(M\land N)\to K \iff \lnot(M\land N)\lor K\iff (\lnot M\lor \lnot N)\lor K\iff \lnot M \lor(\lnot N \lor K)\iff M\to (\lnot N \lor K)\iff M\to (N\to K)$$     ..... Or we could just do truth values until it becomes intuitive.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalence:

$P \to Q \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor Q$

is known as Implication

Using Implication and other elementary equivalence principles you can manipulate your expression to get the one from Wikipedia:

$((A\to B) \land \neg B) \to \neg A$

$\Leftrightarrow$ (Implication)

$\neg ((A \to B) \land \neg B) \lor \neg A)$

$\Leftrightarrow$ (DeMorgan)

$(\neg (A\to B) \lor \neg \neg B) \lor \neg A$

$\Leftrightarrow$ (Association)

$\neg (A \to B) \lor (\neg \neg B \lor \neg A)$

$\Leftrightarrow$ (Implication)

$\neg (A \to B) \lor (\neg B \to \neg A)$

$\Leftrightarrow$ (Implication)

$(A\to B) \to (\neg B \to \neg A)$